# Configure IP addresses for virtual interfaces only

Tags: centos, ifconfig, interface

In my current CentOS ifconfig, I have `eth0` and the range of virtual interfaces `eth0:0 - eth0:3` each taking up a unique address in the subnet `69.xx.yy.194/29` (gateway = `.193`, broadcast = `.199`)

Now I only get one shot at this because I access the server via remote terminal, so I thought I'd ask here to double check what I'm about to do.

I'm guessing if I perform `ifdown eth0`, it will take everything, including the interfaces down. What I would like is to be able to take down any one of my 5 services running on the machine by plugging them each into their own virtual interface (note, I only have 4 interfaces right now)

Therefore, is it possible to not have an IP address assigned to `eth0`, and rather put it on `eth0:0` so I end up with 5 interfaces each with a separate address?

(Will this have unexpected side-effects for my PuTTY connection?)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that taking down eth0 will take down all cirtual interfaces based on eth0.

Instead of taking the interface down, you could reconfigure it with the address 0.0.0.0 - this will keep the interface up but without an IP address. I just verified that the following sequence worked perfectly:

The server originally has the address 172.17.8.10 on eth0, default gateway is 172.17.8.1

```
draal:~ # ifconfig eth0:0 172.17.8.11
draal:~ # ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
draal:~ # ping 172.17.8.1                                    
PING 172.17.8.1 (172.17.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.           
64 bytes from 172.17.8.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.119 ms   
64 bytes from 172.17.8.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.244 ms   
^C                                                           
--- 172.17.8.1 ping statistics ---                           
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.119/0.181/0.244/0.063 ms            
draal:~ # ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8C:98:44  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe8c:9844/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                         
          RX bytes:1002 (1002.0 b)  TX bytes:1940 (1.8 Kb)     

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8C:98:44  
          inet addr:172.17.8.11  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

When you're doing this, it's highly likely that your SSH connection will be interrupted. I would start by SSH:ing to one of the virtual interfaces; as long as you don't do `ifcfg eth0` down, that session should not be interrupted.

I would also advice you to setup an at job or cron job  that resets all interfaces to their previous state after 5 minutes. If your new setup works, you can cancel the at job, but if it doesn't, you'll be able to get back in after a few minutes.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me. What is your ifconfig-eth0 file like?

Comment: How does it not work? What happens?

Comment: eth0 is not brought back online if its IP address is 0.0.0.0

I can't really provide much more than this as it requires me to contact the datacenter to get them to attach a KVM